# Add-Printer with Network Printer fails

Tags: powershell

When I use `Add-Printer -ConnectionName '\\server\Printer'` from a local PowerShell environment it succeeds.

When I use the same command, but wrapped in an Invoke-Command like so:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'someServer' -Credential $creds -Authentication CredSSP -ScriptBlock { Add-Printer -ConnectionName '\\server\Printer' }
```

it fails saying

```
'\' is an invalid character.
```

I'm guessing it's connected to different levels of user profile being available locally vs remotely, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

**Edit**: To update this, I've had to abandon this approach as I couldn't get it to work. My work-around has been to use

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /ga /c\\computerName /n\\someServer\Printer /q
```

Which works, though it does something slightly different to the Add-Printer cmdlet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure why you're seeing that error. I'm sure it'll be something to do with how it's handling passing through the string.

However, you shouldn't really need to run it through `Invoke-Command` as `Add-Printer` has two options within itself to add printers to remote computers.

You can specify single machine with the `-CompuerName` parameter:

```
Add-Printer -ComputerName 'someServer' -ConnectionName '\\server\Printer'
```

You can also specify a (or multiple) CimSessions with the `-CimSession` parameter, allowing you to hit a bunch of machines at once.

A caveat with this command to be aware of is that it only works on Server 2012/ Windows 8 and above (including the remote target).

Comment: Add-Printer with -ComputerName returns "Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters". When I create CimSession with `New-CimSession -ComputerName 'someServer' -Credential $credentials -Authentication CredSsp` I get the same error "The specified server may not exist, or the sever or printer name is invalid. Names may not contain ',' or '\' characters." But since it's a network computer it needs '\' and it worked locally...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem, but I was trying to loop through a list of shared printers from a print server then add all of them to the local machine. Jump to the bottom if you want to see my solution.

The following returns all of the shared printers as objects:

```
$printerList = Get-Printer -ComputerName PrintServer | where Shared -eq $true
```

The following should have looped through all my printers and added each one:

```
foreach ($printer in $printerList) { 
    Add-Printer -ConnectionName "\\PrintServer\$printer.SharedName" 
}
```

Instead, I supposedly run into the same error as the OP:

> Add-Printer : The specified server does not exist, or the server or printer name is invalid.  Names may not contain ',' or '\' characters.
>   At line:1 char:38
>   + ... nterList) { Add-Printer -ConnectionName "\PrintServer\$printer.SharedNam ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_Printer:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_Printer) [Add-Printer], CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070709,Add-Printer

Needless to say, I'm very puzzled by those results because when I test what is going on, I see the following:

```
Write-Host $printer.ShareName
printerName
```

Great! Why doesn't it work in double quotes though? I am intentionally using double quotes to return the contents of the $printer variable:

```
Write-Host "$printer.ShareName"
```

> MSFT_Printer (Name = "printerName", ComputerName = "PrintServer", DeviceType = 0, Type = 0).ShareName

Rather than mess with a CimException likely due to typecasting or who knows what (and yes, the ShareName property is a simple string already, it's not a hash table or a nested funky datatype of sorts), I did a simple `ToString()` as a workaround:

```
$printerList = Get-Printer -ComputerName PrintServer | where Shared -eq $true
foreach ($printer in $printerList) { 
    $printerStr = $printer.ShareName.ToString()
    Add-Printer -ConnectionName "\\PrintServer\$printerStr" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well `ToString()` didn't resolve it for me. It was the "not required" parameter `-ComputerName`. I was running `remove-PrinterPort -Name $port`, which resulted in the following error:

`The specified server does not exist, or the server or printer name is invalid. Names may not contain ',' or '\' characters.`

After banging my head, and Googlin', I finally added the computer name as a test like this `$env:computername`, I tried using a "." before, because I thought that meant local computer but, it didn't work, just stalled.

After adding the computer name, the ports, and drivers were removed without error.

`get-help Remove-PrinterPort` shows that `-Computer` name is not required but, it does seem to be required:

```
-ComputerName [<String>]
        Specifies the name of the computer from which to remove the printer port.

        Required?                    false
        Position?                    named
        Default value                none
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?  false
```